# Is special relativity really a phenomenon or just a result of a bunch of light hitting us at once?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

Apologies for using layman/vague/incorrect terms as I'm not a physicist.

We know that Proxima Centauri is located 4.25 lightyears away from Earth. Which means that any light hitting us from Proxima Centauri is 4.25 years old. But, all the light in between 4.25 years ago and the present time is still on its way to Earth. So, if we hop on a spaceship and head straight for Proxima Centauri, the faster we move, the more recent light hits our eyes. Hence, we experience its 4.25 years history faster (as more of the recent light hits us faster). Special relativity might explain this as the world "moving faster through time" from our perspective, but that can also be explained via the above described intuitive phenomenon.

I feel like Special Relativity must predict more things otherwise it is surprisingly simple and intuitive.

Comment: Among other things, special relativity predicts that an old school cathode ray tube television works, and Galilean relativity combined with electricity and magnetism predicts that it doesn't.

Answer (score 6):

> but that can also be explained via the above described intuitive phenomenon.

Actually, if you work out the math, it cannot.

What you are describing is called the Doppler effect. This is an effect that is predicted by classical physics. The Doppler effect also arises in relativity. However, although the concept and the basis is the same, the actual detailed math is different.

The relativistic Doppler effect includes an additional term called time dilation that is not part of the classical Doppler effect. Experiments show that the relativistic Doppler effect is correct and the classical Doppler effect is simply a low-speed approximation which can be used when the time dilation term is negligible.

Answer (score 2):

What you have described is the relativistic doppler shift. There is much more to special relativity than that. The other main effects predicted by special relativity are:

Light moves at the same speed relative to everything.

No object can move relative to any other at a speed equal to or greater than the speed of light.

Newton's second law, and the arithmetic addition and subtraction of velocities are approximations that become progressively inaccurate as the speeds involved increase, and utterly inaccurate at speeds approaching the speed of light. In a given reference frame, the magnitude of the force required to accelerate an object in that frame approaches infinity as the speed of the object in that frame approaches the speed of light.

Mass can be converted into energy, and vice versa.

Two reference frames moving relative to each other have tilted planes of simultaneity. This leads to effects known as time dilation and length contraction.

The elapsed time between two events is greater for a stationary observer present at both events than it is for a travelling observer present at both events (aka the twin paradox).

While the relativistic Doppler effect is quite easy to understand, some of the other effects I have summarised above can appear counter-intuitive when one first encounters them; they are readily (and often) misunderstood and many have been the cause of controversy and even rooted disbelief.

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed more to special relativity, than the fact that light takes a finite time to travel to you.

In my opinion, a good place to start to understand why special relativity is weird, is to think about the constancy of the speed of light.

If you are in a car stopped on the side of the road, and are passed by another car traveling at 60 miles per hour, you can accelerate and match speed with the car so it is not moving relative to you. You could even accelerate to a higher speed so that the distance between you and the car shrinks, and you eventually catch up with the car. This follows from the usual way we combine velocities in Newtonian mechanics.

Now imagine a photon whizzes past you at the speed of light. You might think, ok I can't go at the speed of light, but I can get in my (super-fast) car and go at 1/3 the speed of light, so that the speed of the photon relative to me is only 2/3 the speed of light. **This is not what special relativity predicts.** Special relativity predicts that even if you accelerate to 1/3 of the speed of light (relative to your original rest frame), the photon will *still* be traveling at the speed of light relative to you. In fact, velocities add in a different way in special relativity, than they do in Newtonian mechanics.

It may take a few readings of that paragraph to get the idea. A completely normal reaction is to be baffled and say "but how can that possibly work?" If you have that reaction, you have taken your first step to appreciating special relativity. In fact it is such a weird proposition that there's only really one way to develop a consistent framework in which it is true. The rest of the formalism (Lorentz transformations, time dilation, length contraction) follow from this assumption (plus a few other technical assumptions, like the idea that the laws of physics should be the same in any inertial reference frame and that we can ignore gravity and curved spacetime).

Answer (score 1):

The classical effect that you describe is not related to time dilation. It makes things looks faster when you approach the light and slower when you get away from it. Time dilation, instead, always makes a moving object to seem running slower (in this case the star, which is moving relative to the rocket).

Time dilation is not an effect of how things look like when light reaches you, but how things look like relative to my synchronized clocks, independently of when light reaches you.  That is, imagine that space is filled with clocks, all synchronized and stationary relative to you. Imagine also that the clocks record any events that happen at their location. Then, you know what happened and when, once you go an look at the clocks (or equivalently receive a signal from the clocks), as you do not have immediate access to that information.